# How can I add a Facebook Like box to my blog?

Tags: facebook, blog

I want to add a Facebook Like box similiar to what Mark Suster has done on his [blog](http://www.bothsidesofthetable.com/).  It's a like box with the number of fans and a few pictures. The blog I'm putting it into is custom build.

Comment: Here are the official instructions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like Edit: it's a Like Box without the stream. Here are the instructions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box And the wiki: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Like_Box

Comment: Thanks. It appears that you must also get the Unique id. You can get it back being logged into facebook and https://graph.facebook.com/<ID>. If you need additional help view these instructions http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, Alex, but would you mind putting a summary of what's contained at the links so the answer can stand alone?

Comment: @jonsca Just added with updated content.

Answer (score 1):

The Like Box is deprecated now. You should use the [Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) now, which

> lets you easily embed and promote any public Facebook Page on your website. Just like on Facebook, your visitors can like and share the Page without leaving your site.

To do this,

1. Go to [Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) and configure your page.
2. Click on **Get Code**
3. Include the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) on your page once, ideally right after the opening body tag.

   ```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
   ```
4. Place this code wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

   ```
   <div class="fb-page"></div>
   ```

Comment: Thanks!  I should have waited a bit longer before converting the other to a comment.